# Will an Arduino Nano work instead of Teensy 3.2?

Tags: programming, adafruit, serial-data, keyboard, components

I hope this is ok to post here and I appreciate any suggestions or help and opinions/facts to make this work.

First off I’ve **Never** programmed an Arduino device!

I was looking at this project:
https://learn.adafruit.com/pinball-controll-ipad/duo-pinball-teardown

I would like to use the cheaper **Arduino nano** type board, and use the provided code to program it.

I have the same device (pinball Duo controller as in the project) just wanted to know if I attempt this will the **atmega328P Nano** achieve the same results?

Thank you,

Shlade

Comment: No, Nano doesn't have native USB so it can't emulate the keyboard like teensy does. You can use Arduino Micro/Leonardo/Pro Micro or similar.

Comment: @KIIV ;-) I'd love to see answers written as answers... Isn't this site supposed to be helpful right on the front page?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use Adruino Nano, because in this project the Teensy board has been used as an USB Keayboard and Nano has separate communication chip (FTDI or CH430) that can't emulate USB keyboard.

However you don't have to use Teensy boards, you can use any board that has native USB support. For example Arduino Micro, Arduino Pro Micro, Arduino Leonardo. All are using Atmega32u4.

You can probably find many more boards with different MCUs (usually they don't have any dedicated communication chip). I think for example RPi Pico, Seeed studio xiao BLE (on this one you might be able to pull even bluetooth mouse emulation), ...

If you want further infos here is the pinmap for you :
[image: arduino nano pinout]
[image: teesny 3.2 pinmap]